# Prove by induction that $n^3 = (n^2-n+1)+(n^2-n+3)+...+(n^2+n-3)+(n^2+n-1)$

Tags: induction

I have an exercise that asks me to prove that $n^3 = (n^2-n+1)+(n^2-n+3)+...+(n^2+n-3)+(n^2+n-1)$ by induction, but I got stuck: I don't know what I can do.  Could you please give me some hints? 
Examples:
$$1^3=1 \,,
2^3 = 3+5 \,,
3^3=7+9+11 \,,
4^3=13+15+17+19$$
Note: As the exercise asks me to prove the identity $1^3 + ... + n^3 = (1+2+...+n)^2$ afterwards, I kindly ask you not to use that.

Note2: I'm aware of this identity: $ 1+3+...+2k-1 = k^2$
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am confused about your series ... it goes from -n+1 to -n+3 to ... to +n-3 to +n-1 ?!?

Comment: @Bram28 Seems like the terms here are $n^2+k$ for $k$ ranging from $-n+1$ to $n-1$ by twos.

Comment: There's a straightforward way to prove this without induction: each term is $n^2+k$, with $k$ ranging from $-n+1$ to $n-1$ by twos. How many terms are there? What can you say about the $k$ parts?

Comment: @Y.Forman Ah, so, say, for n=4 the added terms are -3,-1,1, and 3. Got it, thanks!

Comment: I updated my question. By the way, the book explicitly asks for an induction proof, even though I easily found a classic one.

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: @Shaun This problem is from D. E. Knuth "Fundamental Algorithms" (exercise 1.2.1-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** To get from the $n$-term sum
$$ (n^2-n+1) + \dots +  (n^2+n-1)$$
to the $n+1$-term sum
$$ ((n+1)^2-(n+1)+1) + \dots + ((n+1)^2+(n+1)-3) + ((n+1)^2+(n+1)-1)$$
we can add $(n+1)^2-n^2-1$ to each of the first $n$ terms, and then add in the last $((n+1)^2+(n+1)-1)$ term.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} (n^2-n+2k-1)= ?
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use your second note.